# How to use the text parameter with the google fonts API for just one font type

Tags: html, fonts, google-webfonts

I am using 2 google font families and have them declared as:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

I want to add one font-family (Parisienne) and I only need the ampersand character (&). I understand this can be done using the 'text' parameter (https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

However if it is possible I want to add it to the existing link tag. I have tried the following:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700|Parisienne&text=%26&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

But doing it this way seems to write the logic as "load all 3 font families but just the amperand character for each one". Which is kind of expected but I at least wanted to try it. I tested this and indeed the only character in each font that works/is downloaded is the ampersand

To make it work I have 2 seperate link elements:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Parisienne&text=%26&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there any way to use only one link tag and have it load the entire Roboto and Monteserrat families and only the ampersand character of the Parisienne family? If not then having 2 seperate link tags is fine but if there is any way to do this with just one link tag it would be nice to know how.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, the *key* `text` counts for the entire request URL. Thus, no way we can achieve that with a single `<link>`.